# Makefile Error - Linker input file unused

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I'm trying to run a simple makefile that looks like this:

```
T=-ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror
a.out: test.o extra.o
    gcc $(T) -c test.o extra.o

test.o: test.c test.h 
    gcc $(T) -c test.c

extra.o: extra.c extra.h 
    gcc $(T) -c extra.c

clean:
    rm *.o a.out
```

But I seem to be getting warnings telling me that "linker input file unused because linking not done"

I tried removing the "-c" from the a.out directive, after the gcc, but that produced to give me more problems. I'm not sure how to go about proceeding from here, any ideas/input would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I'm running the program by "make -T", also removing the -c from a.out, causes the error" invalid symbol index"

Comment: Sorry I'm running it like "make -T", also if I remove the -c, I get the problem "invalid symbol index"

Comment: See answer...but `make -T` is odd; what does that do?  The 'invalid symbol index' suggests that you should remove all the `.o` files and run from the start again.

Comment: My Assigment specifies to use the makefile which is build with the T command (First line in the makefile).

Comment: `make -T` doesn't do that...whatever else it does.  The T macro is fine; the usage of it is fine.  Drop the `-T` from the command line.  (I note that GNU `make` 3.81 does not recognize `-T` as a valid option.  Either it is new or you are using a different variant of `make`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `-c` from the `a.out` command:

```
a.out: test.o extra.o
    gcc $(T) test.o extra.o
```

or, better:

```
a.out: test.o extra.o
    gcc $(T) -o $@ test.o extra.o
```

or, still better:

```
extra: test.o extra.o
    gcc $(T) -o $@ test.o extra.o
```

The error message is normally because you specify something like `-lm` on a command line with `-c`, but you're not doing that here.  OTOH, you are listing object files with the `-c` option — that'll generate the warning:

```
gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror -c test.o extra.o
                                   ^ this one, here
```

Those `.o` files are the linker inputs, but you're not linking.  Drop the `-c` and you will generate `a.out`.  That should proceed OK.

I think this is the first time I've seen a makefile used to build `a.out`.  It is unusual in the extreme — not precisely wrong, but definitely not the way you normally use `make`.  It has built-in rules to build programs from single source files, such as `example` from `example.c`.  Normally, you give a program a meaningful name based on one of the source files.  Note that creating a program `test` is usually a bad idea; there is a standard `test` command built into the typical shell and confusion is rampant.